# Displaying the header content only when accessed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to think of a way how people can see the 
header content only in a full screen display (no matter how big or small a user's browser screen size is) first before they
start scrolling down the page. Here is what I mean.

[image]

I want people to see the top red bordered area only when they access the website. I dabbled with `vh` or `vw` but I'm not sure if that's the right way to handle this issue.

```
<header class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
          <h3>Idealogic</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="login">
          <a href="#"><p>Log In</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="signup">
          <a href="#"><p>Sign Up</p></a>
      </header>

      <section>
          <h3 class="welcome">
            You Think. <br /><p class="indent">We Design.</p>
          </h3>
      </section>
    </div>

      <!-- Nav Wrapper !-->
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>How does it work?</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Pricing</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Education Discouts</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    <!-- Nav Wrapper Ends !-->
  </div>
```

Here is the header html section. Should I wrap the entire header contents with a div class then go from there? I'm fairly new to the front-end development. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sorry to ask for clarification, but are you saying that you only want the top area visible on desktop browsers and not mobile ones?  If so, and you are using a server side language such as php, it would be better to detect the browser type on the server side and only include this part for desktop browsers. That way you will not be slowing mobile users down by having them download a big picture they can't look at.  The other way to handle this is css media queries based on content size (I know, its screen size related, but this is common practice and does not rely on browser sniffing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to make sure the `<section>` fills the viewport's height and then subtract the header and nav from the viewportHeight. Don't use `vw` or `vh` as they don't have the greatest browser support.

```
jQuery('section').height(viewportHeight - 100);
//The - 100 is the amount of pixels to subtract. This should equal the height of the header-wrapper and nav-wrapper.
```

This should work for you. I would also recommend placing your `<a>` elements inside of the `<li>` elements in your HTML.

---

Otherwise you can use HTML and CSS and accomplish this using position absolute as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/9jL0mLqp/